# Converting another language to powershell or using the language in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint

I have found this code

```
// "url" is the full destination path (including filename, i.e. https://mysite.sharepoint.com/Documents/Test.txt) 

// "cookie" is the CookieContainer generated from Wichtor's code 
// "data" is the byte array containing the files contents (used a FileStream to load) 

System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; 
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest; 
request.Method = "PUT"; 
request.Accept = "*/*"; 
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"; 
request.CookieContainer = cookie; request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"; 
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us"); 
request.Headers.Add("Translate", "F"); request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); request.ContentLength = data.Length; 

using (Stream req = request.GetRequestStream()) 
{ req.Write(data, 0, data.Length); } 

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
Stream res = response.GetResponseStream(); 
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(res); 
string rawResponse = rdr.ReadToEnd(); 
response.Close();
rdr.Close();
```

Which apparently successfully uploads a large file to a **sharepoint** site, however my code is in **powershell**. Is there anyway to use this in powershell in its form now or even convert this to powershell?

Comment: Keep in mind that PowerShell has explicit commands to support web requests. There are two: `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod`.  Have a look at the help on these commands and check out the examples in the help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C# code is, as a general rule, easily translated to PowerShell because C# uses the exact same underlying type system and runtime environment as PowerShell (.NET).

A few things to watch out for:

### Variable assignment

C# is a type-safe language, meaning that the compiler guarantees the *type* of a variable and its value, as seen in your example:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url); 
//     ^          ^      \________________________/^      
//     |          |                  |             |
//     |    variable name            |    statement terminator ";"
// type-name                         |
//                    static method call that returns a 
//                     value we can assign to "request"
```

In PowerShell:

1. Types are implicit, variables are not bound to a single type (thus no need for a type name)
2. Variable references are prefixed with `$`
3. To access static members (like the `Create()` method above), we use the following syntax:

   - `[Namespace.TypeName]::Member`
4. The `;` is unnecessary, a linebreak after a statement implies termination

Thus, the above statement becomes:

```psh
$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
```

---

### Booleans

The two C# boolean keywords (`true` and `false`) are, in PowerShell, represented by two automatic variables called `$true` and `$false`:

```psh
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::Expect100Continue = $false
```

---

### `using`

PowerShell doesn't have a construct comparable to [C#'s `using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). To ensure disposal of an object that implements `IDisposable`, you'll have to use `try`/`catch`/`finally`:

```psh
$req = $request.GetRequestStream()
try{
    $req.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
} catch {
    throw $_
} finally {
    if($req){
        $req.Dispose()
    }
}
```

---

### Constructors

PowerShell doesn't have a `new` keyword for object instantiation, but provides the `New-Object` cmdlet that can wrap C# constructors:

```psh
$rdr = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $res
```

Rather than:

```cs
StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(res);
```

In PowerShell 5.0 and newer, you can now invoke constructors using the `new` static method as well:

```
$rdr = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($res)
```

---

### Type casting

PowerShell supports both *explicit casting* that in C# would look like `(typename)variable`, but again, with square brackets instead of parentheses:

```psh
[System.Net.HttpWebResponse]$request.GetResponse()
```

And (as of version 3.0) it supports *unchecked casting* as well (still with square brackets):

```psh
$request.GetResponse() -as [System.Net.HttpWebResponse]
```

The latter will return `$null`, rather than throw an error, if the cast is not possible.

---

This should get you translating in no time. From the comments in your codefind, it seems you might need to translate "Wichtor's code" as well, in order to generate the `$cookie` container.

Comment: Not sure when it was added, but it does now have ```::new()``` for instantiating types.  E.g. ```[System.IO.StreamReader]::new($res)```

Comment: @Patrik Added in PowerShell 5.0, the public preview of which had just been released when this question was asked :-)

Answer (score 2):

See below example. I had to wrap the code in class and function.

```
$code = @"
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
public class MySharepointTools 
{
    public void UploadFile(System.String url, System.Net.CookieContainer cookie, System.Byte[] data)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; 
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest; 
        request.Method = "PUT"; 
        request.Accept = "*/*"; 
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"; 
        request.CookieContainer = cookie; request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"; 
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us"); 
        request.Headers.Add("Translate", "F"); request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); request.ContentLength = data.Length; 

        using (Stream req = request.GetRequestStream()) 
        { req.Write(data, 0, data.Length); } 

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
        Stream res = response.GetResponseStream(); 
        StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(res); 
        string rawResponse = rdr.ReadToEnd(); 
        response.Close();
        rdr.Close();
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp 

$tools = New-Object MySharepointTools
```

Now you can call the method using

```
$Tools.UploadFile(url, cookie, data)
```