# Count the visible rows in DataGridView using Powershell

Tags: powershell, datagridview, visible, rowcount

After I've used `$DataGridView1.Rows[$row.Index].Visible = $false` to hide some rows, I need to count how many are visible now.

If I use `$DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount.ToString()`

I get this result:

```
int GetRowCount(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates includeFilter)
```

So, if I use `$DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount($DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)`

I would expect a number of the visible rows in my DataGridView, but it returns an exception:

```
    Cannot convert argument "includeFilter", with value: "", for "GetRowCount" 
to type "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates": "Cannot convert null 
to type "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates" due to enumeration 
values that are not valid. Specify one of the following enumeration values and 
try again. The possible enumeration values are 
"None,Displayed,Frozen,ReadOnly,Resizable,ResizableSet,Selected,Visible"."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error indicates, you'll need to supply a value of type [`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewelementstates):

```
$DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount([System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates]::Visible)
```

Comment: All I could find about this was related to C#, but I was unable to translate that code into Powershell. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer may be useful for future reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629114/712649)