# Convert string to DateTime in Powershell from CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm having the weirdest and most annoying problem with dealing with a string here that I need to convert to DateTime.

I'm doing the exact same thing from 2 different CSV files - it works perfectly on the first one, keeps returning an error on the second one.

```
$userDateOut = Get-Date $sourceLine.Date_OUT -Format "dd/MM/yyyy"
$userDateOut = ($userDateOut -as [datetime]).AddDays(+1)
$userDateOut = Get-Date $userDateOut -Format "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

In the first CSV, Date_OUT is just `31/12/2021` for example, and in the second one it's `31/12/2021 0:00:00`.

So before the 3 lines to create `$userDateOut`, I do

```
$userDateOut = $sourceLine.Date_OUT.SubString(0,10)
```

Which makes me end up with the same type of variable as with the first CSV

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $userDateOut = $sourceLine.Date_Out.Substring(0,10)
PS C:\Windows\system32> $userDateOut
31/12/2021
PS C:\Windows\system32> $userDateOut.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

However, with this variable, I'm getting

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $userDateOut = Get-Date $userDateOut -Format "dd/MM/yyyy"
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "31/12/2021" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:25
+ $userDateOut = Get-Date $userDateOut -Format "dd/MM/yyyy"
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

And I don't know why...  Can someone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Format` just converts `[datetime]` to a `[string]` - it doesn't influence parsing of input strings in *any* way.

For that, you need `[datetime]::ParseExact()`:

```
$dateString = '31/12/2021'
# You can pass multiple accepted formats to ParseExact, this should cover both CSV files
$inputFormats = @(
  'dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss'
  'dd/MM/yyyy'
)

$parsedDatetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, $inputFormat, $null)
```

You can then use `Get-Date -Format` to convert it back to an intended output format if needed:

Comment: By googling I had found DateTime ParseExact but only for C# and couldn't figure it out for Powershell.  Problem solved !

Comment: @MichelBalencourt In that case you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627662/converting-another-language-to-powershell-or-using-the-language-in-powershell/31629114#31629114) useful as well! :)